# rename columns if present in a dataframe - pipe operator with if else

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm importing and tidying a large number of data sets and trying to streamline my code.

While the data sets are similar, more recent ones have different column headings.

For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 3), b = 4:6, c = 5:7)

df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 1, 1), b1 = 1:4, c = 8:11)
```

I have created a function to tidy this data, ensuring that, where it is present, b1 is renamed to b, and filtering a = 1 in all cases, as follows (this is a simplified version of the various bits of wrangling).

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
  if(any(grep('b1', colnames(x)) > 0)) {
    x %>%  
      filter(a == "1") %>%
      rename(b = b1) 
  } else {
    x %>%  
      filter(a == 1)
  }
}


fun1(df1)
```

However this still requires that `filter(a == 1)` step to be repeated within the function for both `if()` and `else()`

I would therefore like to `filter(a == 1)` all datasets, and then apply the `if()`, `else()`, `rename()` stage, e.g.:

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
x %>%
filter(a == "1") %<%
  if(any(grep('b1', colnames(x)) > 0)) {
      rename(x, b = b1) 
  } else {
  }
}

fun1(df1)
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
Error in if (.) any(grep("b1", colnames(x)) > 0) else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (.) any(grep("b1", colnames(x)) > 0) else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What am I getting wrong?

Thanks
Jack

Comment: I am confused to what you are trying to do. Could you show how you want to combine `df1` and `df2` and what the final result will look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also chain the `if else` part as shown below:

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    {if('b1'%in% names(.)) rename(., b = b1) else .} %>%
    filter(a == 1)
}

fun1(df2)
  a b  c
1 1 1  8
2 1 3 10
3 1 4 11

 fun1(df1)
  a b c
1 1 4 5
2 1 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` with `rename_with` and `filter`, so we get a function that is more versatile, and will work with unexpected names in any of the variables.
First rename with a function that extracts only the letters from the names, then filter the a==1, all within a single pipe chain.

```
library(dplyr)

my_wrangler<-function(df){
        df %>% rename_with(.cols=everything(), ~str_extract(.x, "[[:alpha:]]")) %>%
                filter(a==1)
}

> my_wrangler(df2)
  a b  c
1 1 1  8
2 1 3 10
3 1 4 11
```

Comment: This is helpful, though makes me realise that my reprex was imperfect as the colum to rename in the fulk data set is not actually changed by addition of a number, but is actually a different text string!

Comment: regexes are flexible, if you update the data, we can edit accordingly. Or you can use `rename` as in the other excellent answeres provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
  store <- x %>%filter(a == "1")
    if(any(grep('b1', colnames(store)) > 0)) {
      rename(store, b = b1) 
    }
}

fun1(df2)
  a b  c
1 1 1  8
2 1 3 10
3 1 4 11
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Solution**
Here is a far more concise way of doing it suggested by dear Mr. Onyambu again:

```
df2 |> 
  subset(a == 1) |> 
  (\(.)setNames(., sub('^b1$', 'b', names(.))))()

  a b  c
1 1 1  8
3 1 3 10
4 1 4 11
```

We could also do it using base R pipe like this (inspired by Mr. [Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu) as always). I defined a custom function where you only need to change the data set at the start of the pipe line:

```
df1 |>
  {\(x) {
    tmp <- subset(x, a == 1) 
    if("b1" %in% colnames(tmp)) {
      names(tmp)[names(tmp) == "b1"] <- "b"
    } 
    tmp
  }  
}()

  a b c
1 1 4 5
2 1 5 6
```

Or with `df2`:

```
  a b  c
1 1 1  8
3 1 3 10
4 1 4 11
```

Comment: Op doesn't want the repetition. Ie you are using subset twice, instead of once

Comment: Thanksss Mr. Onyambu. First I tried to use it only once but with this base R pipe it threw an error and I don't know how I could fix it. I mean moving `subset` outside the `if` statement wasn't working.

Comment: You could consider doing subset then renaming. The two are mutually exclusive

Comment: It was an interesting idea! I was wondering why they are mutually exclusive. Thank you very much again I edited my code :)

Comment: you could do something like `df2 |>
  subset(a == 1) |>
  (\(.)setNames(.,sub('^b1$', 'b', names(.))))()`

Comment: This is amazing, I added this solution too with your permission. Thank you for this valuable suggestion. It's a pleasure learning from you.

Comment: I did not know there was a base r pipe. I'll stick to the tidyverse solution I think, but appreciate the varied options

Comment: @jfefleming Yeah it's a new feature of R. So that's indeed the point of using stack overflow here, where you could see different solutions.